# loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Ive searched this for over an hour now and no ones post helped me with my problem so i need to post i guess lol

I have some pretty simple code for a grunt task im trying to run but im getting an error.

```html
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initconfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON ('package.json'),

        uncss: {
          dist: {
            files: {
            'css/style.css' : ['index.html']
            }
          }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['uncss']);

};
```

my package file is as follows:

```html
{
  "name": "Grunt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "grunt",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "tt"
  ],
  "author": "troy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-uncss": "^0.4.3"
  }
}
```

The Error im getting is:

Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > TypeError: undefined is not a function
> >     Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: did you get any answer ??